Why are some UniswapV2 Pair addresses non deterministic
According to Uniswap V2 Factory, the pair address of any given pair can be calculated deterministically, as seen in the createPair function:
function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair) {
    require(tokenA != tokenB, 'UniswapV2: IDENTICAL_ADDRESSES');
    (address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
    require(token0 != address(0), 'UniswapV2: ZERO_ADDRESS');
    require(getPair[token0][token1] == address(0), 'UniswapV2: PAIR_EXISTS'); // single check is sufficient
    bytes memory bytecode = type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode;
    bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1));
    assembly {
        pair := create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), salt)
    }
    IUniswapV2Pair(pair).initialize(token0, token1);
    getPair[token0][token1] = pair;
    getPair[token1][token0] = pair; // populate mapping in the reverse direction
    allPairs.push(pair);
    emit PairCreated(token0, token1, pair, allPairs.length);
}

Making an implementation in go to determine the pair address:
func getPairAddress(tokenA common.Address, tokenB common.Address, factory common.Address) common.Address {
    tokens := []common.Address{tokenA, tokenB}
    sort.Slice(tokens, func(i, j int) bool {
        return tokens[i].Hex() < tokens[j].Hex()
    })
    token0 := tokens[0]
    token1 := tokens[1]

    salt := crypto.Keccak256Hash(append(token0.Bytes(), token1.Bytes()...))

    data := []byte{}
    data = append(data, []byte{0xff}...)
    data = append(data, factory.Bytes()...)
    data = append(data, salt.Bytes()...)
    data = append(data, constants.V2PairInitCodeHash.Bytes()...) 
    hash := crypto.Keccak256Hash(data)

    pairAddress := common.BytesToAddress(hash.Bytes()[12:])

    return pairAddress
}

This works perfectly, yet I have found an example (and there are surely more) of a token having a non-expected pair address.
Token: 0xbEc771D15F7E67bC0bb4571c7Eb409228cC6FeF9
Expected pair: 0x0d0e649590a3dFa1DC863cd91a30376382D69b1F
Actual pair: 0x113fEf6A431d4789be9083eb53910679f7c0f18E
How is this possible?

How can it be a casing thing if I am using the common.Address primitive from go ethereum? Doesn't it deal automatically with checksum? And I am also copying addresses directly from etherscan.

@kfx I just checked and it looks like the sorting part of the algorithm is wrong, meaning that some times it doesn't select token0 and token1 appropriately. Any suggestion on how to make that work?

It was a problem caused by the comparison mechanism. token0 should be the token between tokenA and tokenB with the smallest address.
A fix is using big.Int comparison:
func GetV2PairAddress(tokenA, tokenB, factoryAddress common.Address, initCodeHash common.Hash) common.Address {
    comp := tokenA.Big().Cmp(tokenB.Big())

    var (
        token0 common.Address
        token1 common.Address
    )

    if comp < 0 {
        token0 = tokenA
        token1 = tokenB
    } else if comp > 0 {
        token0 = tokenB
        token1 = tokenA
    } else {
        log.Fatal("tokenA and tokenB can't be the same")
    }

    tokensHash := crypto.Keccak256Hash(token0.Bytes(), token1.Bytes())

    data := []byte{}
    data = append(data, []byte{0xff}...)
    data = append(data, factoryAddress.Bytes()...)
    data = append(data, tokensHash.Bytes()...)
    data = append(data, initCodeHash.Bytes()...)

    hash := crypto.Keccak256(data)

    // Convert the hash to an Ethereum address
    address := common.BytesToAddress(hash[12:])

    return address
}

